# Why is a dead man like a plumber's candle?

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning

[Here](http://opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2007/05/03/when-that-guy-died-on-my-show/?_php=true&_type=blogs&_r=0) I read the following about a man who had just died:

> He was the ghastly pale of a plumber’s candle.

What exactly is meant? As far as I can google, a plumber's candle is just a shorter and thicker one, perhaps containing more stearic acid ([source](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_a_plumber's_candle)). What has all that to do with colour?

Comment: "*pale*" is the clue.  It's the color of the plumber's candle that is being compared.

Comment: @Jim I understand the word pale. That's why I asked "What has all that to do with **colour**?" :) But I still don't see what's special about a plumber's candle's colour.

Comment: Even if I'd never seen or heard of a "plumber's candle," given the context I'd deduce that a plumber's candle is a ghastly pale color not unlike the color of a dead man's skin.

Comment: @Jim That's my deduction as well. But I want confirmation. The author is using that expression as if it were a known idiom - but apparently it isn't. So I want to hear from people who are familiar with it.

Comment: Then do a google image search for "plumber's candle" and notice that the majority of the candles are white.  Then realize that plumbers probably don't use candles to melt lead nowadays in the age of handheld torches and electric soldering irons so this must have been prevalent many years ago when materials weren't quite so pure so that plumber's candles probably weren't quite so white. So picture a little more off-white color for the candles and there you are- something that looks very similar to the bloodless skin of a dead man.

Comment: @Jim: so are a majority of household candles, and the majority of votive candles, and tealights, and pretty much any candle that's made primarily of paraffin (and isn't dyed). The simile in the quote is like saying something is "as green as a milk-vetch leaf in spring" - sure, a milk-vetch leaf is green in spring, but so are an awful lot of other, far more common (and commonly-known) things.

Comment: @Marthaª- I agree, but what's your point?  That he chose plumber's candle and not something far more common?  The author is free to make any simile he wants. He doesn't have to confine himself to well-known idioms or well-known household objects.  Maybe his dad had some old plumber's candles in a cardboard box in the deep dark corner of the basement when he was a kid so he associates them with scary things-  who knows.  The point is he picked them as having a similar color to the color he wanted to describe. Without more context, like maybe the guy was a plumber I doubt it goes much deeper.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about plumber's candles, dead men's skin,  and writer's choices of similes and not about the English language itself.

Comment: @Jim: oh, come off it already!

Comment: @Jim Presumably, writers' choices of similes do have something to do with the English language.

Comment: Really, Isn't this not a question of writer's style and better on Writer's SE?  I'm not trying to be difficult.  Typically we, on ELU, deal with word meaning, grammar, etymology, etc.  I think we all agree we know the meanings of the words being used.  We aren't questioning the grammar or sentence construction.  We are only debating about why the author chose to use a plumber's candle in his simile instead of something else that appears to be more obvious to the set of people currently debating about it here.  I don't see that there can be a definitive answer here.

Comment: It really doesn't have anything to do with English specifically-  The sentence might as well be:  Il était le livide de la bougie d'un plombier.  And your question would remain the same: Qu'est-ce que tout ca a à voir avec la couleur?

Comment: If this were a common idiom, this would be a language issue. But if it's just limited to that one instance, it's just about the author's ideas about candles, not about the English language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The ghastly pale of a plumber's candle* is not an idiom in English. But it's not difficult to understand, either.

The melting point of lead is 621.5° F. A plumber's candle, used to melt lead and keep it molten while he worked would need to be thicker to avoid needing to adjust the lead pot as the candle burned down.

[image: candle flame]

The picture you see here is of a [leaded wick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candle_wick) (outlawed for a few years now), which serves to keep the wick upright and to increase the efficiency of wicking, so that the flame was hotter and the melt pool was larger. (Most candles today have a flat-braided wick that curls down towards the candle and self-consumes. The upright ones often needed trimming with scissors.)

The hottest part of the flame is the [white flame](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45421/where-is-the-candle-hottest) just above the orange flame (above the blue flame). This can get to 2000°F. So the container for lead would be placed near the middle of the flame to get maximum contact with that part of the flame.

Plumbers generally worked in somewhat darker spaces before the advent of acetylene torches/etc. Imagine the (thicker) candle with a pot spreading the flame out across the bottom: less light from the flame to radiate outward (the "light" being "hidden" by the pot.) In the dark, what you would mostly see is the glowing wax stick in the dark. Strearic acid (which was the main ingredient of tallow candles) is very white, not yellow as pictured here (this might be a beeswax candle.)

So, it's not hard to imaging a pale white plumber's candle glowing in the dark appearing ghostly, or, if it was a man's skin, ghastly. The flame would be rendered less visible by the pot, and candle just glowing, kind-of disembodied from the flame, would seem eerie, out of common experience.

It's a nice simile. I'm glad you brought it up.

Comment: Well-researched, interesting, and plausible. +1